# Where can I get FuelPHP Migration document (except for official doc)

Tags: php, migration, fuelphp

I expect for Rails like migration function on FuelPHP.
Nonetheless, there's no detailed document on official web of FuelPHP.
http://fuelphp.com/docs/general/migrations.html

But some says FuelPHP has migration function like Rails.

Where can I get the detailed document?

Comment: As far as I can tell, both migrations work the same. Judging by the both DOCs

Comment: But the thing is there's no detailed document for FuelPHP migration. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://www.fuelphp.com/api/classes/Fuel.Core.Migrate.html

Comment: Oops! That's what I am looking for. No matter how much times I checked I couldn't find it. Thanks!!

Comment: But if possible, I could get more detailed document(examples, usages...)
Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can do everything in a migration class, just make sure your `up()` and `down()` methods are symmetrical, that your down migration can revert everything your up migration does. 

If you have migration dependencies, your method can return false, it it is skipped are retried once all other migrations have run. you need this for example if you have dependencies on a package.